# Color formatting excel file row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have dataframe where I have 2 Date columns. I have to compare them and if they are different then whole row should be colored. Please check the picture.  [image]

Please guide me how can I do that in python. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create styles in helper DataFrame and [export to excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date1':['19/3/2011','15/5/2015','18/8/2018'],
                   'Date2':['19/3/2011','1/1/2019','18/8/2018']})

print (df)
       Date1      Date2
0  19/3/2011  19/3/2011
1  15/5/2015   1/1/2019
2  18/8/2018  18/8/2018

def highlight_diff(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: red'
   c2 = '' 
   m = x['Date1'] != x['Date2']

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   df1.loc[m, :] = c1
   return df1

(df.style
   .apply(highlight_diff,axis=None)
   .to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False))
```

[image: pic]

Comment: is it possible just to color only the second cell of date 2 column?

Comment: @Abdullah - Sure, change `df1.loc[m, :] = c1` to `df1.loc[m, 'Date2'] = c1`

Comment: @Abdullah - accepting answer working with your new requirement?

Answer (score 2):

a bit cleaner using a function

```
def format_df(x):
    if x.Date1 != x.Date2:
        return ['background-color: red'] * len(x)
    return [''] * len(x)

df.style.apply(lambda x: format_df(x), axis=1).to_excel("file.xlsx",index=False)
```

Edit 1: if you want only the second column to be highlighted,

```
def format_df(x):
    if x.Date1 != x.Date2:
        return ['']+['background-color: red']
    return [''] * len(x)

df.style.apply(lambda x: format_df(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: is it possible just to color the second cell of second date column.

Comment: it raise some value error: "ValueError: arrays must all be same length"

Comment: @Abdulla, how many columns do you have , the second code will work only for `two` columns. For multiple columns: for e.g. if your `Date2` is the forth column, then `return ['']*3 + ['background-color: red'] + [''] * (len(x)-4)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`DataFrame.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) and [`DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date1':['19/3/2011','15/5/2015','18/8/2018'],
                   'Date2':['19/3/2011','1/1/2019','18/8/2018']})

df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color: red']*df.shape[1] if x['Date1'] != x['Date2'] else ['']*df.shape[1], axis=1).to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

and you get:

[image]